# Shortcut to remove the first parameter of a function everywhere it is called

Tags: java, intellij-idea

We are evaluating IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 for our project based on JAVA. I have to remove the first parameter of a few functions, because now they are of no use. The problem is that each of these functions is called more than 50 times in the entire project. 
Do I have to manually remove the first parameter everywhere the function is called? Are there any shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the "change signature" feature (CTRL+F6).

Comment: it's actually called "change method parameters", at least in 14.1.5.

Comment: Haha, it's change signature in 14.1.4 :-D Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the function name:

> Refactor->Change Signature

According to @jwenting in 14.1.5 is "Change method parameters"

then you have to choose

> Method Calls: Modify

(the other option here is to create an overloading method)